# Post form, signed_request and session in Facebook Canvas

Tags: facebook, forms, session, post, facebook-canvas

I'm developing a Facebook app that will run in canvas. This is the scenario (I think it's very common). This is all server-side implementation.

Being:

```
APP_URL: https://apps.facebook.com/xxxxxx/
CANVAS_URL: https://myexample.com/facebookApp/
```

1. **Step 1** (index of the app) has a form. It has `action="CANVAS_URL/step2"` (note that is not the app Url). In order to use `signed_request` in the next step, it has an hidden field `<input type="hidden" name="signed_request" value="<?php echo $_POST['signed_request'] ?>" />`
2. **Step 2**: it receives the info of the form and stores it in a `Session`, then parses the signed_request. This works OK. I store it in the Session because I want to save it to a database *after* the user is authenticated. If user was logged on to the app, I redirect him to `APP_URL/step3`; if not, I redirect him to login dialog, with `&redirect_uri=APP_URL/step3` . In both cases, note that the step 3 is `APP_URL/step3` (as I need `signed_request` again to check if user has authenticated and another data). All redirections are made with JavaScript: `<script type="text/javascript">window.top.location = "URL";</script>`
3. **Step 3**: now I want to save the data previously stored in the Session. **BUT** as the user is navigating through FB canvas, the session data is not available.

I tried several combinations. If the form is sent to `APP_URL/step2` (instead of `CANVAS_URL/step2`, in order to create the session for `APP_URL`), I can't retrieve the posted data (because it is sent to FB, not to the `CANVAS_URL`).

I thought about using the `session_id` to recreate the Session in `APP_URL`, but I'm afraid that it isn't a very secure approach. I'm sure that there must be a better workaround.

Comment: Why not authenticate the user _before_ they fill out the form? Or deviate from the server-side-only approach, and use the JS SDK to log the user in to your app – that way, you can keep the filled-out form and submit it afterwards.

Comment: @CBroe: I started with server-side approach as it seemed simpler. Instead of mixing server-side (storing to Session, DB) and client-side (FB login, permissions, post to strem), I thought that it would be more clever to use only one "side". I think that what I'm suggesting is simple and fast, there must be one workaround.

Comment: Well, saving the session id into a cookie would be one “workaround” … with the obvious third-party-cookie-problems across different browsers and configurations as a drawback. But is passing the session id as URL parameter really that unsecure in this scenario …?

Comment: @CBroe Well, not really, but I want to do it clear and transparent for the user. Adding the session id to the url (it works) is not the best practice, I suppose...